# json to HashMap<Date, Integer>

Tags: java, json

I have to convert json Strings like this

```
{"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015":2131165194,"Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2015":2131165194,
"Thu Dec 11 00:00:00 MEZ 2014":2131165194,"Fri Dec 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2014":2131165194,
"Mon Jan 19 00:00:00 MEZ 2015":2131165194,"Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 MEZ 2014":2131165194,
"Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2015":2131165194}
```

into a HashMap.

Is it really necessary to write a parser?

I try to avoid this, because I never made this bevor, and it seems quite difficult. I would be glad for any help and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by  I never made this bevor ? what is bevor? and your question is opinion based I guess?

Comment: I never wrote a parser (sorry, my english skills are not the best^^)

Comment: first do not be sorry cuz you did not say anything bad. you are here to improve your programming skills. just trust me if you get vote down, do not take it personal. just see it how you can make yourself better so try to see how you can improve your answer cuz you got close vote because your questions seems too abroad to a person

Comment: You need two parsers. One for JSON and one for the Date. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

Comment: Ok, thank you, when there is no easier way ( like gson.fromjson(...) with the Gson library), I will try it with writing a parser on my own

Comment: Why? GSON should parse the string into an object. Each date is a field in the object. Iterate over the fields and use the DateFormat to parse the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keys are unique – you can use the next code

```
String s = "{\"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\n" +
            "\"Thu Dec 11 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\"Fri Dec 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\n" +
            "\"Mon Jan 19 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\n" +
            "\"Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194}";
    Map<Date, Long> map = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'MEZ' yyyy").create().fromJson(s, new TypeToken<HashMap<Date, Long>>() {
    }.getType());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned  about Gson , you need to set the [date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the Gson object(you can build it via [GsonBuilder](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html)) and then declare `TypeToken<Map<Date, Integer>>` after that just invoke `fromJson` E.g.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\n" +
                "\"Thu Dec 11 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\"Fri Dec 12 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\n" +
                "\"Mon Jan 19 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 MEZ 2014\":2131165194,\n" +
                "\"Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194}";

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Date, Integer>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'MEZ' yyyy").create();

        Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
}
```

Output

```
{Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 CET 2015=2131165194, Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 2015=2131165194, Thu Dec 11 00:00:00 CET 2014=2131165194, Fri Dec 12 00:00:00 CET 2014=2131165194, Mon Jan 19 00:00:00 CET 2015=2131165194, Wed Dec 10 00:00:00 CET 2014=2131165194, Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 2015=2131165194}
```

Comment: change the string to: String json = "{\"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194,\"Tue Jan 13 00:00:00 MEZ 2015\":2131165194}";

do you know, how to prevent duplicate key exception?

Comment: @user1050819 It is illegal for JSON object to have two attributes with same name. If you really want it, then use `gson 1.6`